# Zsh completion with up and down arrows

Tags: shell, zsh, autocomplete

I used oh-my-zsh for a while and found one of its nice features, where I could complete my command using up and down arrow keys.

I want to recreate the feature, and even browsed it source code and this is what I have so far: https://termbin.com/vlaj in my ~/.zshrc.
Say my history is like this:

1 `nvim hello-word.sh`

2 `nvim fibonacci.c`

3 `nvim cmatrix.py`

Now if i had `$ nvim he`
and i press up arrow key, it becomes `nvim cmatrix.py` , and not `nvim hello-word.sh` as it would in oh-my-zsh.
I found this to be helpful, but it doesn't fix it: https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/issues/1720

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this plugin fulfill your need?

https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-history-substring-search

Comment: If it weren't for the fact that this is the accepted answer, we would likely delete it as "a link-only answer" or convert it to a comment (it has been flagged for deletion twice now). Ideally, the answer should be expanded with an explanation of how to use the plugin to solve the original user's issue.

Comment: The explanation is: installing plug in and configuring it. It's not possible to include all that lengthy install guide here.

Answer (score 9):

If you are looking for completion based on the prefix of your command, zsh includes what you need natively (taken from this [blog post](https://coderwall.com/p/jpj_6q/zsh-better-history-searching-with-arrow-keys)).  Simply include the following in your `.zshrc` (adjusting the `bindkey` keycodes if necessary for your OS):

```
autoload -U up-line-or-beginning-search
autoload -U down-line-or-beginning-search
zle -N up-line-or-beginning-search
zle -N down-line-or-beginning-search
bindkey "^[[A" up-line-or-beginning-search
bindkey "^[[B" down-line-or-beginning-search
```

Answer (score 2):

All the solutions didn't work, but I finally found this one:

```
# Make zsh autocomplete with up arrow
autoload -Uz history-search-end
zle -N history-beginning-search-backward-end history-search-end
zle -N history-beginning-search-forward-end history-search-end
bindkey "$terminfo[kcuu1]" history-beginning-search-backward-end
bindkey "$terminfo[kcud1]" history-beginning-search-forward-end
```